# How do I get back to new version of Google Analytics in Google AdWords

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-adwords

I set up a new Google AdWords account to try to sort out my links with Google Analytics once and for all. I have setup the new account as an admin on the Analytics account I want to link.

I stupidly clicked "use old version" on the Analytics page of my AdWords account and now can't find how to get back to using the new version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### Google Analytics

It seems strange, I tried to do the same, clicked on "Old Version" but I can easily change again to new version by clicking the corresponding link on top bar.

[image]

### Google Adwords + Analytics

[image]

Is "New Version" link not there for you?

Comment: Its the Analytics tab within my adwords account, rather than google analytics itself but thanks

Comment: @Toby I tried to do the same with AdWords + Analytics and there are links also there to move from "New Version" to "Old Version" and viceversa.